# Tableau comparison calculation between integer dates

Tags: tableau-api

I'm currently struggling with a calculation I'm trying to create in Tableau so any help you can provide would be great.

Basically I have a calculated field within Tableau called `[ExampleCount]` which is a count distinct based on a simple Yes/No condition.

I have this information displayed on two separate sheets in a dashboard, one filtered for the current activity month and one for the previous.

What I now need to do is have another sheet with the same calculation of `[ExampleCount]` but showing the difference between the current/previous months.

So:  `[ExampleCount (This Activity Month)] - [ExampleCount (Previous Activity Month)]`

The Activity month is an integer value, currently ranging from 1 - 9.

I feel like this should be a simple calculation but I've tried several different methods and have been unable to come up with anything conclusive.

It would also be good if this could change periodically.

Kind Regards,

Plain_Lazy

Comment: Hi Marcus, that should be quite easy with a table calculation. Could you upload a dashboard somewhere so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: Hi Alex, unfortunately it contains confidential data so i can't upload the dashboard, do you have any quick suggestions i should try?